# string.insert in c# doesn't overwrite does it?

Tags: c#

string.insert in c# doesn't overwrite the character that is in the startindex does it?

Comment: Is that what happened when you tested it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For example, the return value of
>   "abc".Insert(2, "XYZ") is "abXYZc".

So, no.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Insert does addition only. Replace does change.

**Edit**: As others pointed out, strings are actual immutable, so both methods will return copy of your initial string. However, the semantic of the operations is as above.

Comment: Replace still does not modify the original string. It returns a new string with the changes made.

Answer (score 2):

No. Strings are immutable. `string.Insert` returns a new string with the inserted value. It does not change the old string.

```
string newString = oldString.Insert(3, "foo");
```

`oldString` does not change. But "foo" is now in `newString`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in c# are immutable. They cannot be changed except by reflection or unsafe code (and you should never do this).

All methods on string which 'modify' it instead **return a new string** with the appropriate modifications.

Since insert is placing one string within another the result of an insert of string `s1` into string `s2` will be a string of `length s1.Lnegth + s2.Length`, no characters are lost.

Answer (score 1):

No. It just tells it where to insert the character, so if you had the following

```
string x = "ello".Insert(0, "h");
```

the string would actually read "hello".

Answer (score 0):

No, definitely not.

But the best practice is to use StringBuilder instead of immutable strings if you're doing changes to the string in-flight.

[Here's](http://dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-1) a nice overview.